PX4/Ardupilot: How to update quadcopter state over USB/UART?
I'm interested in integrating a SLAM system with a quadcopter using an existing controller for low level control.
What I'm wondering is, how can the absolute state be updated via the SLAM system?
Ex, I transmit position, orientation, velocity over GPS or UART and the controller updates it's absolute position.
